# Query on type expressions in ML

Tags: functional-programming, types, sml

All,

Here is the type expression which I need to convert to a ML expression:

```
int -> (int*int -> 'a list) -> 'a list
```

Now I know this is a currying style expression which takes 2 arguments:
1st argument = Type int
and 2nd argument = Function which takes the previous int value twice and **return a list of any type**

I am having a hard time figuring such a function that would take an `int` and return `'a list`.

I am new to ML and hence this might be trivial to others, but obviously not me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have to add that deriving an SML expression from a type signature doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  A type signature only tells you part of the story.  Essentially for a given type, there may be infinitely many expressions that inhabit that type.  It only makes sense to specify a type for something when you know what you want it to do.  You use that combined intention _and_ the type to write the implementation.  For example, the signature 'a list -> 'a list could be a sort function, or a reverse function, or any number of other things. It doesn't tell you enough to write the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an `int` and a function `int*int -> 'a list`. You're supposed to return an `'a list`. So all you need to do is call the function you get with (x,x) (where x is the int you get) and return the result of that. So

```
fun foo x f = f (x,x)
```

Note that this is not the only possible function with type `int -> (int*int -> 'a list) -> 'a list`. For example the functions `fun foo x f = f (x, 42)` and `fun foo x f = f (23, x)` would also have that type.

Edit:

To make the type match exactly add a type annotation to restrict the return type of f:

```
fun foo x (f : int*int -> 'a list) = f (x,x)
```

Note however that there is no real reason to do that. This version behaves exactly as the one before, except that it only accepts functions that return a list.

Comment: The definition you have sent has the type; `val foo = fn : 'a -> ('a * int -> 'b) -> 'b` . My query is how can a function which does not take a list, return a list, which does not happen in the definition you have given above

Comment: @darkie15: Have you seen the edit? The new version matches your type exactly.

Comment: Okie just saw the edit. It's working as per the type expression I needed. Can you please let me know how to derive such ML expression based on the type expression given? I want to be able to solve any such derivations given .